# Html5 input type number formatting

Tags: android, iphone, html, windows-phone-8, input

I have this page where i use the input type number. so that it will show the numeric keyboard on wp, android and ios device .

But my problem is that if the user use a culture info on the device for. lets say Denmark. the numeric keyboard shown use , instead of .

But the input number won't accept , only .
Anyone got a idea how this can be done?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: it's a html5 page. included jquery angularjs and bootstrap

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When retrieving the value with jquery it is returned with a . decimal separator. Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="number" name="myNum" id="myNum">
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
  <hr/>
  <code></code>
  <script>
    $("#submit").on("click",function() {
      var numericValue = $("#myNum").val();
      $("code").html(numericValue);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

http://output.jsbin.com/xixunewowe

Comment: But it doesn'rt output anything if we enter a numeric value with ','

Comment: It does for me in Chrome on Windows. What browser and device are you using?

Comment: In my example I do not submit the form. I use jquery to get the value. When submitting the form the html5 input validation kicks in and maybe that is causing you problems?

Comment: @PaulLernmark have you tried this in mobile browsers? this is really where the problem is.

Comment: I have tried http://output.jsbin.com/xixunewowe on my Androd phone with Lolipop and on my iPad. Both Safari and chrome. Have you tried to set the  step="any" attribute on the input field?

Comment: just got it working, was something in my code that blocked it, don't know why. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `lang` attribute to `en` in the `<html>` element or the `<input>` element itself to force decimal point as input syntax. For example:

```
<input type="number" name="myNum" id="myNum" lang="en">
```

However the user's environment may even override this, in which case the only alternative would be to include a message requiring decimal point rather than comma.

This is a good write-up of locale handling for the number input type:
https://www.aeyoun.com/posts/html5-input-number-localization.html

UPDATE:

Another alternative would be to stop the form from validating the input by using the `novalidate` attribute in a `<form>` element, like so:

```
<form novalidate>
  <input type="number" name="myNum" id="myNum">
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This would allow anything, even non-numbers, so you'd have to set up the JavaScript code to check and handle the value.

UPDATE AGAIN:

Just thought of one more alternative — use the `pattern` attribute to do a regular expression check and use the plain old `text` input type. For example:

```
<input type="text" name="myNum" id="myNum" pattern="[0-9.]*">
```

Advantage: You get to control exactly what users can input.

Disadvantage: The keyboard on mobile devices will not be the numeric keypad.

Note that HTML input types can be spoofed so you still need to do server-side validation.